# Laravel: json field undefined

Tags: jquery, json, laravel, laravel-4

I have used json responses many times with Laravel, but I don't know why this time the data is `undefined`.

Basically what I'm doing is loading a section of the page (the login form) with ajax.

This is the script:

```
function render(url) {
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        $('#content').empty();
        alert(data['view']); /* undefined */
        $('#content').append(data['view']);
    });
}

$(document).on('click', '#login', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#manage-batteries').removeClass('active');
    $('#home').removeClass('active');
    render('/login');
});
```

This is the method:

```
public function login() {
    $view = View::make('users.login')->render();

    return Response::json([
        'view' => $view
    ]);
}
```

The route:

```
Route::group(['before' => 'ajax'], function() {
    Route::get('login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'UserController@login'])->before('guest');
});
```

And the view that's supposed to be loaded but it's not:

```
<h1>Login</h1>

@if (Session::has('flash_error'))
    <div id="flash_error" class="alert alert-danger">{{ Session::get('flash_error') }}</div>
@endif

{{ Form::open('login', 'POST') }}

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('email', 'Email', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}<br/>
    {{ Form::text('email', Input::old('email'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'autocomplete' => 'off']) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('password', 'Password', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}<br/>
    {{ Form::password('password', ['class => 'form-control']) }}
</div>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

So why is the view undefined? What am I missing?

Comment: Isn't it `data.view` rather than `data['view']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the controller, it was throwing an exception and it wasn't logged anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are loading the route `/login` via ajax request will result in a json response like this:

```
{'view':'<h1>Login</h1>...</form>'}
```

You can do this:

```
function render(url) {
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(data);
        $('#content').empty();
        $('#content').append(jsonResponse.view);
    });
}
```

---

P.S. You can optimise this quite nicely like this:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(jsonResponse) {
     $('#content').html(jsonResponse.view)
}
```